# How to run dotnet tests in a specific environment?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit, .net-8.0

I am writing some integration tests and I would like to be able to run something like `dotnet test --environment Test` or something like that and based on that, my integration tests would use appsettings.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.json and use configuration from that file? How can I do that?

Also, if that is possible, would it be possible to switch between environment in Visual Studio?

```cs
public class AppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<IAssemblyMarker>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
        {
            builder.Sources.Clear();
            var defaultSettings = new Dictionary<string, string?>
            {
                { "ConnectionStrings:Database", "Server=localhost,1433;Database=mydb;User Id=user;Password=user;Encrypt=False;" }
            };
            builder.AddInMemoryCollection(defaultSettings);

            // How do I load appsettings.Test.json or appsettings.Whatever.json that would override whatever my InMemoryCollection has specified?
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON data and read its properties value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472168/parsing-json-data-and-read-its-properties-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet test` allows passing environment variables delimited with `=` via [`-e|--environment <NAME="VALUE">` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#options):

> Sets the value of an environment variable. Creates the variable if it does not exist, overrides if it does exist. Use of this option will force the tests to be run in an isolated process. The option can be specified multiple times to provide multiple variables.

```
dotnet test -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Test
```

Which will result in `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Test`. Note that depending on the framework version and setup used you might need to specify `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` since it overrides `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` (see [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments) doc)

Since you are clearing configuration sources you can add back just the JSON files:

```
builder
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
```

Comment: Am I able to decide which environment I want to run the tests for via Rider / Visual Studio or is this limited to the CLI?

Comment: @JrDeveloper For Rider it seems [you can](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing__Test_Runner.html#environment-variables). Also note that that you can try using `builder.UseEnvironment("readenv");` and set environment from any source you want (like custom json file, etc).

Comment: I have, however, another issue. In my ConfigureAppConfiguration, I perform `builder.Sources.Clear()` and then I do `builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json").AddEnvironmentVariables()`, but when I debug the app all the way to my Program.cs, the IConfiguration does not seem to have loaded anything from my `appsettings.Test.json` (I have a `.runsettings` file where I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Test`). Any idea why that could be the case? Also, if for `builder.AddInMemoryCollection()`, it prioritizes the InMemory collection all the time.

Comment: @JrDeveloper yep, the `WebApplicationFactory` explicitly sets environment to `Development` - see my previous comment.  I will try to create a working [mre] but only tomorrow. For now you can try adding `CreateWebHostBuilder` overload where you will call base one and invoke `UseEnvironment("somehow_read_environment_from_where_you_want");` on the result before returning it.

Comment: The funny thing is, in Program.cs, when I access the environment name, it does show "Test", so it did load the name itself correctly, but the environment IConfiguration is not loaded at all from appsettings.Test.json.

Comment: After some more time trying out things, I found the issue. In my WebApplicationFactory's ConfigureWebHost, before `AddJsonFile()`, I needed to call `builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. The reason for this is that I added my `appsettings.Test.json` to my tests project, rather than my web application / API project, so I guess by default, the base path was that of the web application, not the test project's.